# Verilog HDL syntax error at test_bench_lb2.v(14) near text "genvar"; expecting "end"

Tags: syntax-error, verilog

**I am new one in Verilog and I need to write a simple test bench, but I get an error and I cannot understand why it is**
Here is my code

```
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ns

module test_bench_lb2;

reg [12:0] in_lines_tb;
wire [4:0] out_lines_tb;
wire error_tb;

localparam  PERIOD = 10;


initial
    begin
        genvar i;
        for(i = 0; i <= 8000; i = i + 1)
            begin
                in_lines_tb = i;
                #PERIOD;
            end
        #(PERIOD*20) $stop;
    end

    
    initial
        begin
            $monitor("time = %time in_lines = %b out_lines = %b error = %b",
                        $time, in_lines_tb, out_lines_tb, error_tb);
        end


    DESHIFRATOR inst1(.in_lines(in_lines_tb), .out_lines(out_lines_tb), .error(error_tb));
    
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    genvar i;
```

should be this

```
    integer i;
```

A `genvar` is a special kind of variable used in a construct called a generate loop. You code uses an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: I changed to integer. But now he writes that -> **loop must terminate within 5000 iterations**
What do I need to do to get exactly 8000 iterations
```
initial
 begin
  integer i;
  for(i = 0; i <= 8000; i = i + 1)
   begin
    in_lines_tb = i;
    #PERIOD;
   end
  #(PERIOD*20) $stop;  
 end
```

Comment: @ЕвгенийМихайлов this is a different question now. You should ask it separately. Most likely the tool you use has a limit on the number of loop iterations. So, don't forget to mention the tool you used in the question.